# Hiding output with grep for lines that contain THIS word, unless THAT word is there too

Tags: grep

I'm piping the output of my script into [grep](/questions/tagged/grep).  I want to hide all lines that contain a certain word ( for example `AAA`), unless that line also contains a different word (`BBB`).

For example, if my output looks like this:

```
AAA  data1
AAA  data2
AAA  data3 BBB
CCC  data4
```

I want to do something like

```
<run_cmd> | grep ???
```

And STDOUT would show

```
AAA  data3 BBB
CCC  data4
```

Any ideas?   If there is an easier solution than using [grep](/questions/tagged/grep), I could use that too.

Thanks in advance

Comment: and what might you have tried yourself?

Comment: Sorry-- I should have put that in my original question.  Basically, I didn't know how to approach this.  I know that I can use 'grep -v' to prevent it from outputting a line.  But if I do that, I cannot pipe it to another grep to see if it had in the other word in it.  Same if I just do a 'grep' on it for the word.    I know grep can do regexp, but I don't know how to do a 'AAA or !BBB' in regexp.

Answer (score 4):

This is much simpler with `awk` instead of `grep`.

```
run_cmd | awk '!/AAA/ || /BBB/'
```

Comment: arrgh, beat me to it by a min, can't win on SO ;-) +1

Comment: Thanks.  In my case, I had to do "run_cmd | awk '\!/AAA/ || /BBB/'"  (escaped the !) else I would get an error saying "/AAA/: Event not found".